# Converting anonymous type to IList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, casting, ilist

I'm getting an error I don't really understand from the following code:

```
public IList<Store> getNearbyStores(double x, double y)
{
    var result = (from T in
                      (
                        (from stores in dc.Stores
                           select new
                           {
                               stores.id,
                               stores.name,
                               stores.city,
                               stores.typeID,
                               stores.latitude,
                               stores.longitude,
                               stores.tag1,
                               stores.tag2,
                               Distance = (System.Double?)(6371 * Math.Acos((double)Math.Cos((double)(Math.PI * x) / 180) * Math.Cos((double)(Math.PI * stores.latitude) / 180) * Math.Cos((double)(Math.PI * stores.longitude) / 180 - (Math.PI * y) / 180) + Math.Sin((double)(Math.PI * x) / 180) * Math.Sin((double)(Math.PI * stores.latitude) / 180)))
                           }))
                  where
                    T.Distance < 5
                  orderby
                    T.Distance
                  select new
                  {
                      T.id,
                      T.name,
                      T.city,
                      T.typeID,
                      T.latitude,
                      T.longitude,
                      T.tag1,
                      T.tag2,
                      T.Distance
                  }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

The error is:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Store>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Joris\Desktop\ShopperNET\App_Code\DAL\DALstore.cs  104 16  C:\...\ShopperNET\
```

How do I convert an anonymous return type to the IList? I figured toList() would fix it, but it didn't.. I've tried some stuff I found around the web, like using just 'List', but none of it really helped me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method signature is expecting a `List<Store>` to be returned, you could try returning that from your LINQ query, e.g.

```
//top bit of query
//.
select new Store()
{
    Id = T.id,
    Name = T.name,
    //etc..
}).ToList();
```

**EDIT:** Following on Pranay's suggestion below, the following should work:

```
var result = from store in dc.Stores
             let Distance = (System.Double?)(6371 * Math.Acos((double)Math.Cos((double)(Math.PI * x) / 180) * Math.Cos((double)(Math.PI * store.latitude) / 180) * Math.Cos((double)(Math.PI * store.longitude) / 180 - (Math.PI * y) / 180) + Math.Sin((double)(Math.PI * x) / 180) * Math.Sin((double)(Math.PI * store.latitude) / 180)))
             where Distance < 5
             order by Distance
             select store;

return result.ToList();
```

Comment: This leads to a new error: `Error 1 Invalid initializer member declarator. ` Not sure what that means, brb google.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem right away. Wouldn't have thought of doing it that way, hadn't heard about the let thingie yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
    select new Store()
    {
      Id = stores.id,
      Name = stores.name,
      ... 
    }
...
```

instead of `select new { }` to select instances of type `Store` and not of anonymous type

(You could replace both occurences but important is the second one since this is what will be returned)

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384261.aspx), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384062.aspx) for type initializer

Comment: I get `Error 1 Cannot initialize type 'Store' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'` when I do that. New error? ;(

Comment: And when I change the first one aswell, I get this `Error 1 Invalid initializer member declarator`. These errors are so vague. First project I do in .NET and it's really bugging me out :(

Comment: Okay; I think I fixed it by doing what you did with the `ID = `. However, I have one field 'Distance' which isn't in my database, so not in my model either. It's kinda like an `AS Distance` in normal SQL. I can't assign it to anything, can I? It's complaining about it now: `Error 1 'Store' does not contain a definition for 'Distance'`. Still learning here :(

Comment: Yes, you need a property or field for `Distance`. You could either extend your `Store` class or consider returnig something else in your method (e.g. a custom class which provides all needed properties)

Answer (score 1):

I thnk you should make user of `Into` or `Let` keywork than you can go for step 2.

Check the post for more details : [Into and let in LINQ ( Let vs Into)](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/05/into-and-let-in-linq-let-vs-into.html)

Example

```
from student in students
                let x = student.Scores[0] + student.Scores[1] +
                    student.Scores[2] + student.Scores[3]
                where x > averageScore
                select new { id = student.ID, score = x };
```